# How can i get first and last record id in yii CGridview?

Tags: yii, cgridview, yii-url-manager, yii-cactiverecord

I want first and last record id form `$dataprovider` which is passed to gridview which i need to pass to this link.

```
array(
         'name' => 'msg',
         'value' => 'CHtml::link(substr(strip_tags($data->msg),0,30)." .....",Yii::app()->createUrl("Mail/view",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey,"flag"=>"inbox","tab"=>'.$tab.',"category"=>'.$category.')))',
         'type' => 'raw',
         'header' => 'Message',
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare two attributes in your controller.

```html
public $first=null;
public $last=null;
```

2. Define a function in controller to render your link

```html
public function renderMailViewLink($data,$row){
               // you can return anything you want here. whether a link or whatever
               // access $this->first->id , $this->last->id

   return CHtml::link($data->anyAttribute,array('someRoute','id'=>$data->id,'first'=>$this->first->id))
}
```

CActiveDataProvider has a method getData(), which return array of all active records.

3. in actionIndex

```html
$dataProvider = $model->search()
$data = $dataProvider->getData();
$this->first = reset($data );
$this->last = end($data);
```

4. And finally in your view

```html
array(
         'name' => 'msg',
         'value' => array($this,'renderMailViewLink'),
         'type' => 'raw',
         'header' => 'Message',
     ),
```

Please note this code is not tested. But thats how it can be achieved